# Seeking list of countries updating their CRS like Australia has changed to GDA 2020

Tags: coordinate-system

Australia has changed to GDA 2020.

Is there a site which lists whether any other countries are updating their CRS?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to check the change requests from the EPSG database. It does not help with the future plans but already accepted changes can be found from https://epsg.org/search/by-name?displayTabs=all#closed-change-request. Most of the changes are minor but you can try to use the text search for finding out the meaningful changes. Probably you must still  have a look at the descriptions.

As an example the change request concerning GDA 2020 is this https://epsg.org/closed-change-request_2018.009/Add-Australia-GDA2020-data.html?